# What exactly are MultiPartEntity and Form Data? How are they used to upload images in android?

Tags: android, multipartform-data

I searched the web but i could only find code related to multipart form data, not explanation of what they are and how they are used?

Comment: In `Multipart form` data you can send data with `String` , `File` and `Byte`too. It has its own different types of body part including `StringBodyPart`, `FileBodyPart`, `ByteArrayBodyPart()` etc etc. It has a also limited boundary to set for your data too. This is the basic understanding for you !

Comment: Sorry..for the late reply...can u also explain how multiPartEntity is different from multiPart Form data

Comment: MultiPart entity means you can send data in bunch with different body parameters like String , File and Byte etc. Also when you see any demo code then you can understand more !

Comment: You can fire your query any time in my room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93330/the-great-gujarati-android-developers-ever also you can mail me too

Comment: No problem. My Mail id also available on my Stack overflow profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally we are sending only string part of data,while in multipart file part is added with string ,so its called multipart.for example We can send multipart data using volley

```
 public class MultipartReq extends JsonObjectRequest {

        private static final String FILE_PART_NAME = "file";
        private static final String STRING_PART_NAME = "text";

        private final File mFilePart;
        //private final String mStringPart;


        MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        HttpEntity httpEntity;
        Context context;

        private Map<String, String> params;
        public MultipartReq(Context context, int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest, Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, File file, Map<String, String> params) {
            super(method, url, jsonRequest, listener, errorListener);

            this.context = context;
            mFilePart = file;
            entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);    
            this.params = params;
            buildMultipartEntity();
            httpEntity = entityBuilder.build();

        }


        private void buildMultipartEntity() {

            try {
                if (mFilePart.exists()) { entityBuilder.addBinaryBody(FILE_PART_NAME, mFilePart, ContentType.create(mimeType), mFilePart.getName());

                    }
                    try {
                        if(!params.isEmpty()){
                            for (String key: params.keySet()){
                                 entityBuilder.addPart(key, new StringBody(params.get(key),ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));

                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        VolleyLog.e("UnsupportedEncodingException");
                    }


                } else {
                    ShowLog.e("no such file");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ShowLog.e("UnsupportedEncodingException");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            return params;
        }


        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return httpEntity.getContentType().getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try {
                httpEntity.writeTo(bos);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
            }
            return bos.toByteArray();
        }


        @Override
        protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
            super.deliverResponse(response);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert bitmap to byte[] using-

```
public static byte[] bitmapToBlob(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (bitmap == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Log.w("bitmapToBlob", "bitmap getHeight = " + bitmap.getHeight());
    Log.w("bitmapToBlob", "bitmapgetWidth = " + bitmap.getWidth());

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,
            Some_value_0_to_100, baos);

    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Use this function to upload image as byte[]

```
private static void postToUrl3(String url_to_upload_on,
    String file_name_with_ext, byte[] byteArray) {

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = null;

try { 

    httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(url_to_upload_on);


    MultipartEntityBuilder reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    reqEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);            
    ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(byteArray, file_name_with_ext);           
    reqEntity.addPart("file", bab);         
    postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity.build());


    httpClient.execute(postRequest);// takes time

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.w("uploadToBlobStore", "postToUrl Exception e = " + e);
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally { 
    if (httpClient != null) {
        Log.w("uploadToBlobStore", "connection.closing ");
        try { 
            httpClient.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("uploadToBlobStore", "connection.closing errot e = "
                    + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    } 
} 
}
```

Edit 1-

Multipart/form data is used in html to send data with multiple parts(as the name suggests).Any kind of data may be added to it ie. string,file,etc.MultiPartEntity is the calss which dose the same thing on java.You can add more parts of data to this entity, for example `reqEntity.addPart("Id", new StringBody("ID"));` or any other kind of body.

BUT please see that to which ever server you are sending this to,that server should work accordingly.I mean if you use `reqEntity.addPart("Id", new StringBody("ID"));` the server should be looking for a field with name "Id" and do some thing with it.The server can also make a response if configured to do it.You may get response using `HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);`

PS-Fellow developers please edit and improve my answer so i can know more too,or if i am incorrect